# Apple pay integration: Decrypted ...But how to send decrypted json to Payeezy expected format

Tags: ios, encryption, xamarin.ios, applepay

After using a couple of algorithms I have successfully decrypted Payment token for apple pay. Below is the JSON for decrypted data. Here I have a question where do I include this decrypted data. Please look the expected Payeezy JSON.

**Decrypted JSON:**

```
{  
   \"applicationPrimaryAccountNumber\":\"48174342340149452\",
   \"applicationExpirationDate\":\"231231\",
   \"currencyCode\":\"840\",
   \"transactionAmount\":3000,
   \"deviceManufacturerIdentifier\":\"050012030162\",
   \"paymentDataType\":\"3DSecure\",
   \"paymentData\":{  
      \"onlinePaymentCryptogram\":\"AkH3827AdEdXwWFACtOjMAACAAA=\",
      \"eciIndicator\":\"7\"
    }
}
```

**JSON that Payeezy expects:**

```
{
    "transaction_type": "purchase",
    "merchant_ref": "order1",
    "method": "3ds",
    "billing_address": {
        "name": null,
        "street": "dsdsds",
        "state_province": "NY",
        "city": "New York",
        "country": "US",
        "email": null,
        "phone": null,
        "zip_postal_code": "11747"
    },
    "3DS": {
        "type": "A",
        "data": "NdCmVw5nMjQq746HYc/VbiZcQZ/zFzeEcM1wVMPruEG4/C/EFhobSkwB5JZJU+t6JuDVXUBiRYuOOC8FTYd+qIm6ckktid9aiGh0f2NDP0INSr59QXmr389RonyUfRYKnBmwsh5UqtI7Iz0AmMtl1PWMdxcCewtjuffs79ahTnFgXsRN+ynuhyDfbdRanlTnYKGoTeVh9eJfheJ1wquO+jiGj+npJ/Oh9bAdlw7iEHrYO2aUkgaMyXZ3foXRAJeimQVQS1y8lU1PPq62zpPrFzidbnnU5fK25pvGFjOdmLsBELZPk5thQEkSaA9p1LSKzWSesHhi0BxZaFPXSA6ANXvYIU2AT0lG+0O0w1URA5Sinyj3YDZVqjuir6rzNN9bB2U2nTQnKMbuGLMS20K8fUKZN/YLJh+AtE6J69+VVSU95mE1nOb8hyabz6E5RmnC5Ze2k6F/hQ75ig==",
        "header": {
            "applicationDataHash": "94ee059335e587e501cc4bf90613e0814f00a7b08bc7c648fd865a2af6a22cc2",
            "ephemeralPublicKey": "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEiaU1SbkYTJy/j5L1t51vtGDh4KlNl5MFPWzo/C8r0WcrktWriz5pdRaDVUDvU++KlDu2iuQsd2xSNKJlFscbDQ==",
            "publicKeyHash": "YmSWN7lj4+A6fVJVPicP8TgS7gI7ougD8rEWB5LXtMM=",
            "transactionId": "31323334353637"
        },
        "signature": "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",
        "version": "EC_v1",
        "applicationData": "VEVTVA==",
        "merchantIdentifier": "order-1",
        "special_payment": "B"
    },
    "recurring": false
}
```

Comment: is there a reason for the C# tag?

Comment: Are you using their iOS SDK?  You shouldn't need to decrypt anything or create any JSON.

Comment: No SDK is available for Xamarin.ios . So I'm trying to send the payload directly and im getting erro response

Comment: Here is a official demo of  `Apple Pay` in `Xamarin.iOS`. You don't need to decrypte data. [Apple Pay in Xamarin.iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios9/Emporium/).